# How to transfer attribute of nearest Point to Line feature?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, point, fields-attributes, line, proximity

**Feature class 1: Addresses (Point)
Feature class 2: Road centerlines (Polyline)**

*Which is the most appropriate tool for transferring the Address attribute (e.g. Road No. or Bldg) to the nearest Road line segment?*

Tools reviewed and rejected

**Attribute transfer ( Spatial adjustment) 
Near/Near table**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best choice is the Spatial Join with Match Option set to CLOSEST.